# Check for pattern recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

*Note i refer to thing as a matrix but it is not, it is just a collection of 1's and zeros

Suppose you have a matrix that is always square (n x n). Is it possible to determine if there exists a single column/row/diagonal such that each item is a 1.

Take the matrix below for instance (True):

1 0 0
1 1 0
0 0 1

Another example (True):

1 1 1 
0 0 0 
0 1 0

And finally one without a solution (False):

0 1 1
1 0 0
0 0 0

Notice how there is a diagonal filled with 1's. The rule is there is either there is a solution or there is no solution. There can be any number of 1's or zeros within the matrix. All i really need to do is, if you have (n x n) then there should be a row/column/diagonal with n elements the same.

If this is not possible with recursions, please let me know what is the best and most efficient method. Thanks a lot, i have been stuck on this for hours so any help is appreciated (if you could post samples that would be great).

**EDIT**
This is one solution that i came up with but it gets really complex after a while.

Take the first example i gave and string all the rows together so you get:

1 0 0, 1 1 0, 0 0 1 
Then add zeros between the rows to get:
1 0 0 0, 1 1 0 0, 0 0 1 0

Now if you look closely, you will see that the distances between the 1's that form a solution are equal. I dont know how this can be implemented though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In search for an elegant solution I came up with this:

```
class LineOfOnesChecker(object):

    _DIAG_INDICES = (lambda i: i, lambda i: -i - 1)

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self._matrix = matrix
        self._len_range = range(len(self._matrix))

    def has_any(self):
        return self.has_row() or self.has_col() or self.has_diag()

    def has_row(self):
        return any(all(elem == 1 for elem in row)
                   for row in self._matrix)

    def has_col(self):
        return any(all(self._matrix[i][j] == 1 for i in self._len_range)
                   for j in self._len_range)

    def has_diag(self):
        return any(all(self._matrix[transf(i)][i] == 1 for i in self._len_range)
                   for transf in self._DIAG_INDICES)
```

Usage:

```
print LineOfOnesChecker(matrix).has_any()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of **n 1**'s and do an **'AND'** for your sets of diagonal elements, row elements and column elements and if any of those AND operation results in a TRUE, then you have your valid pattern.

```
import sys
matrix = [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]
transpose = zip(*matrix)
diagonal1 =  []
for n,elem in enumerate(matrix):
    diagonal1.append(elem[n])
diagonal2 = []
for n,elem in enumerate(transpose):
    diagonal2.append(elem[n])
for row in matrix:
    if reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, row):
        print True
        sys.exit()
for row in transpose:
    if reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, row):
        print True
        sys.exit()
if (reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, diagonal1) or reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, diagonal2)):
    print True
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What about the diagonals then? There are always 2 diagonals in any (n x n). Apart from that though, there must be an algorithm possible for this?

Comment: Yes, I would account for both the diagonals. I have found these kind of questions commonly asked in programming contests. I have used the method I pointed out, using high level language like python.

Comment: I added a possible solution in the edit, let me know if this is something that might work. Basically if you look at all true solutions and count the distance between each element you will see its the same distance(by distance i mean elements). So in the second example i gave the distance is 1 between the items in the first row. The first example i gave, the distance is 3.

Comment: @1337holiday. I could not understand your example. I have added a solution to this response. It will work for any nxn.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the problem, you just need to check whether any row, coloumn or diagonal consists entirely of '1's. This can be done very easily using `all` in Python, so I don't get why you want to do this recursively.

The more obvious solution (in my mind) is something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
boards=[
        ((0,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,0)),
        ((1,1,1),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)),
        ((0,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,0)),
        ((0,0,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,1)),
        ((1,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,0)),
        ((0,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,0)),
        ((0,0,1),(0,0,1),(0,0,1)),
        ((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)),
        ((0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)),
        ((0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0))
]

def check(board):
        for row in board:
                if all(row):
                        return True
        for col in xrange(len(board)):
                vector=[board[row][col] for row in xrange(len(board))]
                if all(vector):
                        return True
        diag1=[board[i][i] for i in xrange(len(board))]
        if all(diag1):
                return True

        diag2=[board[i][i] for i in xrange(len(board)-1,-1,-1)]
        if all(diag2):
                return True

        return False

if __name__=='__main__':
        for board in boards:
                if check(board):
                        print "Yes"
                else:
                        print "No"
```